# NumberPicker con ArrayList

Tags: java, android, array, firebase, numberpicker

Estoy intentando añadir una lista de datos dentro de un numberpicker. Estoy utilizando la libreria de: https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker para el numberpicker.

Asi aparece en mi app:
[image: NumberPicker]

Como pueden observar aparece con [ ] a sus costados y separados por una coma, como puedo eliminar eso? Supongo que ese es el problema.

Estoy obteniendo la informacion desde la base de datos FIREBASE

Mi codigo:

```
IList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Information").child( uploads.getIdPost() )
        .child("CBS1");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        IList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            IList.add(snapshot.getKey());

            String[] data = {String.valueOf( IList )};
            numberPicker.setMinValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(data);
            numberPicker.setValue(data.length);
            numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el formato que deseas obtener, eliminar los corchetes y ","?

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar una exprecion regular , tambien conocida como regex para evitar ciertos caracteres en tu String

```
data.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]|,*$","");
```

Esto evita las `,` y los `[]`